# Bootstrap - have columns disappear as screen narrows

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Presumably common and easy but I'm struggling to find an example when googling (perhaps due to wording).

I have 6 columns each displaying a tile on my screen:

```
X X X X X X
```

As the screen width reduces I'm aiming to have the tiles disappear one by one:

```
X X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X
X X X
X X
```

So a mobile device might only ever display 2 tiles, and a laptop 6.

I've tried declaring a row and 6 columns, but all tiles collapse as one:

```
X
X
X
X
X
X
```

[image]

Comment: `I've tried declaring a row and 6 columns, but all tiles collapse as one:` Can you add that code here please?

Comment: Thanks - added the structure. Presumably the approach is wrong as they all collapse as one in this example also: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_ex1&stacked=h

Comment: You would need to add media queries based on custom width in between mobile and laptop screens. Next time please use the code snippet instead of an image.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">1</div>
<div class="col-md-2">2</div>
<div class="col-md-2">3</div>
<div class="col-md-2">4</div>
<div class="col-md-2">5</div>
<div class="col-md-2">6</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A description  need for answer

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't achieve the desired effect, it's the same as the failed approach I posted (all columns collapse as one together). Is there a way I can word the question better? I'm aiming to have the columns disappear one by one as the screen width reduces.